# Python/tkinter - defining checkbox looping over a string of labels

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, checkbox

I want to define a row of `tk checkbox` widget looping on a list of labels. Everything works fine except that I can't seem to be able to set the `IntVar` value on the `if` statement, although it works for the state. What am I doing wrong?

```
def CheckboxLine(self, frame, fformat=None):
    self.__set_col(0) # set widget column to zero
    var_c = [] 
    widget_c = []

    if fformat is None:
        fformat = ['text', 'excel', 'xml']

    # widget definition
    for item in fformat:
        var_c.append(tk.IntVar(master=frame))
        widget_c.append(tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text=item, variable=var_c[-1]))
        if item == 'text':
            var_c[-1].set(1)
            widget_c[-1]['state']='disabled'
        else:
            var_c[-1].set(0)
            widget_c[-1]['state']='normal'
        widget_c[-1].grid(row=self.__row, column=self.__col, columnspan=1, padx=self.__padx, pady=self.__pady, sticky="nsew")
        self.__next_col()
    self.__next_row()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `var_c` and `widget_c` outside of your function. The reason behind this is unclear to me, unfortunately.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var_c = []
widget_c = []

def CheckboxLine(frame, fformat=None):

    if fformat is None:
        fformat = ['text', 'excel', 'xml']

    # widget definition
    for idx, item in enumerate(fformat):
        var_c.append(tk.IntVar(value=0))
        widget_c.append(tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text=item, variable=var_c[-1]))
        if item == "text":
            var_c[-1].set(1)
            widget_c[-1]["state"] = "disabled"
        widget_c[-1].grid(row=idx, column=0)

CheckboxLine(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: since this is a class, var_c and co should be instance variable, right?

Comment: I assume your function `CheckboxLine` is defined in a class, so yes, i suggest to define the variables `self.var_c = []` and `self.widget_c = []` in the init function of your class and then fill/use it from within the function.

Comment: ok thanks. just out of curiosity, I was tinkering with the code and noticed that adding command, like "widget_c.append(tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text=item, variable=var_c[-1], command=lambda: print(var_c)))" makes eveything works fine, any idea why? :/

Comment: You are right, very interesting - unfortunately i dont have an answer.